# How do I change the color of text in my ListView?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have created an adaptor class but I don't know how to change the color of each item in listview. The default color is black but I want to change it to white.

I do not get anything related to color in auto-complete when I type color. I don't know if I should be changing it in XML or Java.

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

class SongAdaptor extends ArrayAdapter<Song> {

public SongAdaptor(Context context, ArrayList<Song> songs) {
    super(context, 0, songs);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View listItemView = convertView;
    if (listItemView == null) {
        listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    }
```

I want the color of each text item to be whitish but I get the default color which is black.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `getView()` method to change the color of your items like this:

```
private void setListView() {
arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                  this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, answerList){

    //override getView to change the item text color
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        TextView textView = view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        /*YOUR CHOICE OF COLOR*/
        textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.secondaryTextColor));
        return view;
        }
    };
    listView.setAdapter(answersArayAdapter);
}
```

Comment: Can you share the full error? Cannot resolve what method ?